# How to get List list of Saturday for 2 years in Java

Tags: java, android

i am new in java i want to get list of Dates which have Saturday in Current and next year  like 2016 and 2017.pls help

Comment: What is it in your current code that doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find Saturdays and Sundays in A given month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909361/how-can-i-find-saturdays-and-sundays-in-a-given-month)

Comment: Please [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
private List<Date> getSaturdayListOfCurrentYear(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

    int firstDayOfTheYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int rangeToFirstSaturday = 7 - firstDayOfTheYear;
    int currentSaturdayOfYear = 1 + rangeToFirstSaturday;
    int daysInYear = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    List<Date> saturdays = new ArrayList<Date>();

    while(currentSaturdayOfYear <= daysInYear){
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, currentSaturdayOfYear);
        saturdays.add(calendar.getTime());
        currentSaturdayOfYear += 7;
    }

    return saturdays;
}
```

Comment: thanks,this works for me